# Google Merchant Product Feed with multiple items per XML file?

Tags: xml

## The Question

Is it possible to submit more than 1 item in an XML Product Feed to Google Merchant?

## What I have so far

I have found an example in the Google Docs of a **single** "[Data Item](http://code.google.com/apis/shopping/content/getting-started/usingapi-products.html#item)":

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" [...] >
    <app:control>
        <sc:required_destination dest="ProductSearch"/>
    </app:control>
    <title>Wool sweater</title>
    [...]
</entry>
```

## What I'm after

I was expecting something like;

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<entries>
    <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" [...] >
        [...]
    </entry>
    <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" [...] >
        [...]
    </entry>
</entries>
```

Especially since XML is not meant to have more than 1 root element.

## My Research

I have;

- read the [Merchant Center Help](http://www.google.com/support/merchants/)
- read [Google's Content API for Shopping docs](http://code.google.com/apis/shopping/content/getting-started/usingapi-products.html)
- searched [on Google](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=google%20merchant%20product%20feed%20multiple%20items)
- searched [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=google%20merchant%20product%20feed%20multiple%20items)

all so far without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google provides two separate ways for managing items submitted to their Shopping platform (aka: Google Base). The original question appears to be a mix of the two different approaches:

---

## Google Merchant Center Feeds

These are raw XML files which contain a series of items to be added to Google Base.

The [documentation here](http://www.google.com/support/merchants/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188476) shows how to create an XML file with multiple items (Click "Feed Creation Issues" > "Atom 1.0"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0"> 
    <title>The name of your data feed.</title> 
    [...] 
    <entry> 
        <title>Red wool sweater</title>
        [...]
    </entry>
    <entry> 
        <title>Blue bow</title>
        [...]
    </entry>
</feed>
```

Once this file is created with the [correct attributes](http://www.google.com/support/merchants/bin/answer.py?answer=188494), you must [upload it to Google's servers](http://www.google.com/support/merchants/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188477).

Bonus of this method: You can use the same XML file with [TheFind's service](http://merchantblog.thefind.com/2011/01/merchant-newsletter/demystifying-product-feeds/).

---

## Content API for Shopping

This API uses XML as the body of a single call to Google's API for insertion / update / deletion. The XML attributes (linked to as "[Data Item](http://code.google.com/apis/shopping/content/getting-started/usingapi-products.html#item)" in the original question) are slightly different than the [Merchant Center Feed attributes](http://www.google.com/support/merchants/bin/answer.py?answer=188494).

Using this API, you can only talk to Google about a single item at a time, which is where the 'entry' example in the original question is correct:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" [...] >
    <app:control>
        <sc:required_destination dest="ProductSearch"/>
    </app:control>
    <title>Wool sweater</title>
    [...]
</entry>
```

This would be used as the body of an [API call to Google](http://code.google.com/apis/commercesearch/docs/feeds.html#api), such as for inserting a new item:

```
POST https://content.googleapis.com/content/v1/YOUR_MERCHANT_ID/items/products/schema
Content-Type:  application/atom+xml
Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=CLIENTLOGIN_TOKEN

<?xml version='1.0'?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" [...] >
    [...]
</entry>
```

Bonus of this method: You have fine grained control over every item and can insert / delete / update on a per-item basis rather than editing your entire Merchant Center Feed XML file for one small change.